# What would be the best way to purge/clean all null values in a Guava cache?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm currently working with a [Guava cache](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) generated by [Guava's cache builder](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and it has methods to remove all values, remove a set of values by key, and to remove a value by key. No, I cannot just not store the null values because they need to be stored for around 5 minutes.

Is there a better way to remove all null values after N minutes besides completely reimplementing a new cache where I can setup expireAfterWriteNanos when setting a value, or something like:

```
schedule at fixed rate(
   () -> {
      iterate through all keys to save which ones have null values
      cache.invalidate(iterable of all of those keys)
   },
   5 minutes
);
```

I prefer not to use this method because it's expensive to iterate through all of the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing much better than what you describe, but I challenge the assumption that it's necessarily expensive to iterate through all the keys, especially, as you describe, doing it in a background task.

You could, of course, have your cache's "values" store your current values and a time they were created, and then have your cache lookups check that null values are no older than a certain time.

Comment: That's probably better to do if values are constantly added to avoid the risk of deleting something right after it's added.
I'll look around my project's logs, but I think values are added in bulk, so it may not be worth adding that